# What is definition of displacement in context to kinematics?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, definition, distance, displacement

I want explanation of word particular here.
The change in position of a body in a particular direction is called [displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_(geometry)).

Comment: Do you mean displacement which is shortest distance travelled?

Comment: You answered your own question.

Comment: Is the context projectile motion?

Answer (score 1):

The displacement of an object is defined as a (straight line) vector which starts at the initial position of the center of mass and ends at the final position of the CM.

Comment: whats CM? center of mass?

Comment: You can look at the displacement of the CM, but the definition of displacement certainly does not depend on it.

Comment: You can use some other point if the object does not rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Displacement is distance measured from a specific datum to a point. Like distance along the *x*-axis is the distance of the point to the *yz*-plane. It is signed value where a convention for positive directions has been established.

Multiple displacements along perpendicular directions can be combined into a distance magnitude (Euclidean distance) which is always a positive value.

$$ d = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} $$